# Spring Boot can't display .jsp file on the correct endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am very new to Spring Boot framework and want to clarify why I am facing with this issue.

Issue: .jsp file is not shown at the correct endpoint.

this is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return "home.jsp";
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties class

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /webapp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

this is what I have inside home.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Change Titlte</title>
</head>
<body>
            Hello
</body>
</html>
```

and lastly, the project directory

[image]

When I start spring boot app the site looks like this

[image]

Why do you think I can't see the content of home.jsp file?

Any help is appreciated.

Best,

PS: I already added Tomcat Jasper libraries in the pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple [examle](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view). It seems you should not use `.jsp` extension in controller's return statement. Don't forget to specify method of your endpoint. Use `@GetMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping`

Also you'd better switch to Spring MVC [thymeleaf](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) that works good with `html` files. `jsp` - is used mostly for Java EE projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to notice here.

1. Change mapping to /home instead.
2. View resolver is configured already, return "home" instead of "home.jsp".
3. Take Model object as an argument it will be useful.

   home(ModelMap model)